# I am trying to generate data from Oracle SQL in excel format Using Java but I can't find a way

Tags: java

I am novice in JAVA and using Oracle SQL 11g, I have a requirement on my JAVA program to export data from Oracle Database in excel format.
I've searching in youtube but i can't find a way.

Comment: Have you heard of Apache POI?A simple googling will give you various examples of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to export data to excel format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CVS format, witch can be imported in Excel.
 1. Select data from DB.
 2. Convert DTOs to CVS string.
 3. Save them in file.